# Generics -> Polimorphism -> Misunderstanding or Just how it works

Tags: java, generics, generic-list, generic-programming

Let's consider block of code:

```
List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(new ArrayList<Object>); //Line 2
list.add(new LinkedList<Object>); //Line 3
list.add(new LinkedList<Date>); //Line 4
```

Ok:

1. As far as I know polimorphic assigment DO NOT work within Generics

   Question: But in the line: 2, 3, 4 Is there List, ArrayList, LinkedList are not generic for collection with name `list`??
2. Line 4 won't compile, regardless of Date is subtype of Object

   Question: Back to the question 1, Is this means that `Object` and `Date` is case of polymorphism and generics???

Can understand it. Please help.

---

And one more question:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(new Integer(1));
  System.out.print(list.get(0));
```

Output: `1`

Will compile, means no type safety. Why? Even if `List list`- raw type, and `ArrayList<String>` parametrized type, any way is useless. Why?

Comment: `list.add(new List<Object>);` How did you manage to instantiate an interface? Is this your own class and not the Java interface `List`?

Comment: take a look at my answer and let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Also see [*Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/2891664) and [*What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664).

Comment: Invariance of generics only applies to the generic part. Classes and interfaces work the normal way. An `ArrayList<Blah>` is a `List<Blah>`.

Comment: STILL DID NOT GET AN ANSWER WHAT I ASKED: I have List<List<Object>> so why List<Object> which is generic for List can be polimorphicaly subclassed I mean -> it turns out that List - Can be substituted with subclass <Object> - can not A thought that List<Object> this is generic for List and can not be changed. How this is happened????

Comment: And SECOND question: why copmpiler allow you to write List list = new ArrayList<String>(); Particulary ArrayList<String>() even it is usless and I can put anything I want to ArrayList of Strings???

Comment: In the second question, it is the List declaration that defines the type, not the type of the object assigned. For why, you need to look up type-erasure. That is another question. I suggest you read up about it before going further.

Answer (score 1):

FIRST QUESTION:

So the rule is that: **a subclass can do everything that the superclass can do** (and maybe more).

**`A<X>` is a subclass of `B<X>` if `A` is a subclass of `B`**

This is because A can do anything that B can do. Wherever you can use `B<X>` you can use `A<X>`.

For example:

```
List<Object> lo
ArrayList<Object> alo
```

`ArrayList<Object> alo` can do everything `List<Object> lo` can do so it is a subclass.

But:

**`A<X>` is not a subclass of `A<Y>`, even if X is a subclass of Y**

This is because `A<X>` cannot do everything that `A<Y>` can do.

In the case of:

```
List<Object> lo
List<Date> ld
```

`List<Object> lo` can add any object to lo, but `List<Date> ld` can only add dates, so it can't be a subclass.

SECOND QUESTION:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(new Integer(1));
```

Yes - this is very bad and doesn't work. That is why you get a warning.

The `List` declaration is the significant part here in determining the type of `list` and what you can do with it. At runtime, the `ArrayList<String>` just looks like an `ArrayList` due to something called type-erasure, so that will not prevent bad things being added either.

> List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be
>   parameterized

CAVEAT:

The statement **a subclass can do everything that the superclass can do** is a general statement of design intent and not intended to be literally true. You can, of course, find counter examples.

Comment: `a subclass can do everything that the superclass can do`. Not true. Consider a class `A` that has a method that does not have any access specifier (e.g void methodA()). A subclass in the same package as `A` can do whatever `A` can do. A subclass in a different package than `A` cannot do whatever `A` can do because it will not inherit `methodA()`

Comment: Good point - I hadn't thought of it, but kind of a fringe case due to Java strangeness. I think it would confuse things to add it to the answer.

Comment: But it's the main premise on which your answer is based. A premise that is incorrect makes the argument/conclusion incorrect. :)

Comment: No it doesn't if the counter example is not within the scope of the discussion. My argument is a general one about design principles and not about specific implementation details. Going into details would obscure the point. But, your case is interesting anyway.

Comment: You are broadening the scope to justify your answer. The question has been tagged as `java` and my counter example is very much within the scope :)

Comment: STILL DID NOT GET AN ANSWER WHAT I ASKED: I have List<List<Object>> so why List<Object> which is generic for List can be polimorphicaly subclassed I mean -> it turns out that List - Can be substituted with subclass <Object> - can not A thought that List<Object> this is generic for List and can not be changed. How this is happened????

Comment: And SECOND question: why copmpiler allow you to write List list = new ArrayList<String>(); Particulary ArrayList<String>() even it is usless and I can put anything I want to ArrayList of Strings???

Comment: list can add List<Object> so it can also add ArrayList<Object> as ArrayList is a subclass of List, therefore ArrayList<Object> is a subclass of List<Object>.

Comment: Second question - the compiler allows you to do this for several reasons. One important one is that it lets you interact with old pre-generics code. The compiler warns you that it is not safe.

Comment: I know that! But I declare parametrized type for list!!! So that mean that I can substitute parametrized type T with subclass and generic type E I can not substitute with subclass some how. Or what???How compiler identify that rules to apply

Comment: True. I know that too from question two. but!!!!! Why the compiler allow me  to declare parametrized type, to confuse my expectations??? ))

Comment: For question 1, it is not clear what you mean. I suggest edit your question with a specific example. For question two, I think it is already answered. You can mix generics and non-generics code for reasons of compatibility. The compiler doesn't know on the next line you are going to add a bug. At run-time, due to **type-erasure** the parameterised list won't check what you add to it.

Comment: @rghome `At run-time, due to type-erasure`. Not true again. Type erasure happens at compile time itself.

Comment: At run-time ... due to type erasure (which happened at compile time) ...

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know polimorphic assigment DO NOT work within Generics

That's wrong. A reference of type `ArrayList<E>` and a reference of type `LinkedList<E>` are both subtypes of a reference of type `List<E>`.

> Line 4 won't compile, regardless of Date is subtype of Object

A reference of type `LinkedList<T>` is not a subtype of a reference of type `List<E>` (Even if `T` is a subtype of `E`)

> Even if List list- raw type, and ArrayList parametrized type

You declare a reference of type `List`. This is conceptually the same as declaring a reference type of `List<Object>`. Calls to any method (weather static or instance method) are resolved at compile time using the reference type. Since the reference type is `List` (i.e a raw list), the compiler will allow you to add an object of any type to the list. When the class is compiled, the statement `ArrayList<String>` is converted to `ArrayList` by the compiler. This is known as `type-erasure`. This also the reason why you don't face any issues at runtime.

Comment: STILL DID NOT GET AN ANSWER WHAT I ASKED: I have List<List<Object>> so why List<Object> which is generic for List can be polimorphicaly subclassed I mean -> it turns out that List - Can be substituted with subclass <Object> - can not A thought that List<Object> this is generic for List and can not be changed. How this is happened????

Comment: And SECOND question: why copmpiler allow you to write List list = new ArrayList<String>(); Particulary ArrayList<String>() even it is usless and I can put anything I want to ArrayList of Strings???

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know polimorphic assigment DO NOT work within Generics

Actually you are talking about Generics and Inheritence.

so if you have `List<Animal>` i.e list of animal you can add any animal under list like cat,dog but you can cant assign `list of dog` to `list of animal`

Here is the example

```
psvm{
List<Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
list1.add(new Dog());
method1(list1);// compilation error
}

public static void method1(List<Animal> list1) {
list1.add(cat); // Good
list1.add(dog); // Good
}
```

So you did not get any error on line 2/3 but line 4 will give compilation error because `new LinkedList<Date>` is not child of `List<Object>`

**UPDATE:-** if you want to assign `list of dog` to `list of animal` then see below

```
psvm{
List<Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
list1.add(new Dog());
method1(list1);// good
}

public static void method1(List<? extends Animal> list1) {
list1.add(cat); // compilation error
list1.add(dog); // compilation error
}
```

Comment: STILL DID NOT GET AN ANSWER WHAT I ASKED: I have List<List<Object>> so why List<Object> which is generic for List can be polimorphicaly subclassed I mean -> it turns out that List - Can be substituted with subclass <Object> - can not A thought that List<Object> this is generic for List and can not be changed. How this is happened????

Comment: And SECOND question: why copmpiler allow you to write List list = new ArrayList<String>(); Particulary ArrayList<String>() even it is usless and I can put anything I want to ArrayList of Strings???